# Positioning inside of a DIV

Tags: html, css

I always get confused of what the best method is to position content and `divs` inside of a `div`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example, I want the text to positon bottom and center. I can do this by using the position `absoulute` then adding margin.

Is there a better method of doing this which would **avoid** placing content out of the page's layout flow using `absolute` coordinates such as `bottom`, `left`, etc?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with absolute positioning in-and-of-itself-- however, it can be overused and abused, and since it doesn't flow with the page it can be problematic.  For your current case, I'd recommend looking at [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as an option, if your target browsers support it.

Comment: depends if you need it to take space or not - I tend not to use absolute positioning unless I don't want the content to be within the flow of the page

Answer (score 2):

Same thing can be achieved by flex. here is the updated css :-

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox would be ideal for this (Supported on IE11 & all other major browsers).

If you want to impact only `.content`'s content you could do:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.content {
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to impact `.container`'s content considering more content on it, you could do:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <h3>content 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content3">
    <h3>content 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this then align all content inside the container center, because, you've added the justify content element to the .container class?

Comment: Jordan, edited above, just realized what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

By placing an absolute element (child) in a relative placed element (parent), the position (`top|right|bottom|left`) of the child will be relative to the parent, and not the window.

Like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```